# While joining it to wp_posts, how can I put all the values of wp_postmeta table in one row?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to join wp_posts and wp_postmeta table like this:

```
SELECT wp_posts.id, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_author, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE post_type = 'job';
```

But I need the values of the key-value pairs in the wp_postmeta table to be in one row; so that the select statement looks something like this:

```
SELECT wp_posts.id, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_author, wp_postmeta.meta_key1, wp_postmeta.meta_key2, wp_postmeta.meta_key3, wp_postmeta.meta_key4
```

This is how 3 rows appear inside the wp_postmeta table:

**post_id meta_key meta_value**
23841 job_start 1488386107
23841 job_requirements null
23841 job_employment Full-Time

How can I modify by select statement to put the meta_values in one row of the result of the select statement for each post_id? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution that I was looking for. based on post_id, this allows me to put the meta_values of wp_postmeta in a single row with the column values of wp_posts:

```
SELECT  wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title,  wp_posts.post_author, pm1.meta_value as job_start_date, pm2.meta_value as job_end_date 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm1 ON (wp_posts.ID = pm1.post_id AND pm1.meta_key='job_start')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm2 ON (wp_posts.ID = pm2.post_id  AND pm2.meta_key='job_end') 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'job';
```

Here's where I found this solution: http://subharanjan.com/sql-query-to-get-post-and-its-meta_values-as-one-row-of-record-single-data-grid/

I'm sorry if I hadn't framed my question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you add asterisk(*) on the fields of wp_postmeta e.g. wp_postmeta.*
That means you are getting all its columns.

```
SELECT wp_posts.id, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_author, wp_postmeta.*
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE post_type = 'job';
```

Try it.

Comment: Thanks for your response that's a useful advice but my issue is that the values within the wp_postmeta table appear in the form of key-value pairs in the columns meta_key and meta_value.  Is there a way to make all the meta_values appear in one row under the column names of the meta_key associated with that value?
This is how they appear in the wp_postmeta table:

23841 job_start 1488386107
23841 job_requirements null
23841 job_employment Full-Time

Can I put all the meta_values in one row while joining?

Comment: I think you can not do that. Not unless you create a script in PHP that allows you to create a view in your database that displays it in a way you want to display it. You can query all of them but you can not actually put the meta_key as the column name using only MySQL. You can achieve that using PHP